# Perl Command Line Arguments Used In Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, perl

Given various strings in a text file that are in this format:

```
199.72.81.55 - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:01 -0400] "GET /history/apollo/ HTTP/1.0" 200 6245
```

I am trying to read in a number from the command line like this:

```
type small_access_log_Jul95_01.txt | perl FLTR_WLOG_STATUS_CODES.pl 200
```

The "small_access_log" txt file contains a line of the format before given on each line. I am having trouble reading in and using the argument "200" in a search, because it assigns 200 to be the first argument, it seems. 
Here is the code that I'm working on:

```
use strict;
use warnings;


while ( <> ) {

 if ($_ =~ /"[$ARGV[1]]"/){
 print $_;}

 }
```

It is only supposed to print the lines that contain that "200" or whatever is input through the command line.

Here is the working version in python:

```
import sys
import re

TEXT = sys.argv[1]
for n in [x for x in sys.stdin.readlines() if re.search(".*?"+re.escape(TEXT) +"\s([0-9]+)$",x)]:
    print n
```

So what do I need to do differently with the command line in perl to make this work?

Comment: Don't surround your regex with quotes, and do escape the brackets (`\[`) as they denote a character class.

Comment: Actually, what was your intent with the brackets? Were you trying to match `[200]`?

Comment: Yes, that was the intent

Comment: In *nix: `grep 200 log.txt`, in windows `findstr 200 log.txt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter to a Perl program is in `$ARGV[0]`, and the empty diamond operator reads data from the files named in `@ARGV`

You need to write your program like this. It removes the pattern parameter from the end of `@ARGV` before using it in the loop, and takes advantage of Perl's `$_` variable being the default parameter to many operators

The `\Q` in the regex forces all following non-alphanumeric characters to be escaped, and hence taken literally. That includes the square brackets and the *contents* of `$pattern`, which may otherwise be taken as regex metacharacters with a special meaning

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pattern = pop @ARGV;

while ( <> ) {
    print if /\Q[$pattern]/;
}
```

and you should run it like this

```
perl FLTR_WLOG_STATUS_CODES.pl small_access_log_Jul95_01.txt 200
```

#### Update

If you're forced to accept the data input from STDIN instead of from a command-line file name, then you need to do this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pattern = pop @ARGV;

while ( <STDIN> ) {
    print if /\Q[$pattern]/;
}
```

and you should run it like this

```
type small_access_log_Jul95_01.txt | perl FLTR_WLOG_STATUS_CODES.pl 200
```

Comment: It's actually a requirement for me to have 200 as the second parameter, and that's what's causing my issue.

Comment: @TerikBrunson: Okay, simply fixed. You can just remove the pattern using `pop` instead of `shift`. But you must remove it from `@ARGV` otherwise `<>` treats it as a file name

Comment: @TerikBrunson: Please take a look at my recent changes, and the commentary explaining `\Q`

Answer (score 1):

With the command line:

```
perl FLTR_WLOG_STATUS_CODES.pl small_access_log_Jul95_01.txt 200
```

The code would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $arg = pop;

while (<>) {
    print if /\[$arg\]/;
}
```